# Linux Error during make gobject-introspection-1.32.1 

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gobject, udev

I want to install gobject-introspection-1.32.1  on my embedded Linux. 
But during `make` this error message appear.

Do anybody now what to do?

```
-bash-3.2# make                                                                
[ -d gir ] || /bin/mkdir -p gir ; \
    sed \
    -e s,%CAIRO_SHARED_LIBRARY%,, \
    -e s,%CAIRO_GIR_PACKAGE%,, \
    < gir/cairo-1.0.gir.in > gir/cairo-1.0.gir.tmp && mv gir/cairo-1.0.gir.tmp gir/cairo-1.0.gir
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/gobject-introspection-1.32.1'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/gobject-introspection-1.32.1'
  GEN    g-ir-scanner
  GEN    g-ir-annotation-tool
  GISCAN GLib-2.0.gir
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./g-ir-scanner", line 44, in <module>
    from giscanner.scannermain import scanner_main
  File "./giscanner/scannermain.py", line 29, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 881, in <module>
    _inst = Random()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.seed(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 111, in seed
    a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(16)), 16)
RuntimeError: Failed to read %zi bytes from /dev/urandom

make[2]: *** [GLib-2.0.gir] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/gobject-introspection-1.32.1'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/gobject-introspection-1.32.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Do you have a `/dev/urandom` file on your system?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes I have.